# String matching in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to scripting, and I would like to ask you help in the following:

This script should be scheduled task, which is working with Veritas NetBackup, and it creates a backup register in CSV format.

I am generating two source files (.csv comma delimited):

- One file contains: JobID, FinishDate, Policy, etc...
- The second file contains: JobID, TapeID

It is possible that in the second file there are multiple same JobIDs with different TapeID-s.

I would like to reach that, the script for each line in source file 1 should check all of the source file 2 and if there is a JobID match, if yes, it should have the following output:

```
JobID,FinishDate,Policy,etc...,TapeID,TapeID....
```

I have tried it with the following logic, but sometimes I have no TapeID, or I have two same TapeID-s:

Contents of sourcefile 1 is in $BackupStatus

Contents of sourcefile 2 is in $TapesUsed

```
$FinalReport =
foreach ($FinalPart1 in $BackupStatus) {
    write-output $FinalPart1
    $MediaID =
    foreach ($line in $TapesUsed){
        write-output $line.split(",")[1] | where-object{$line.split(",")[0] -like $FinalPart1.split(",")[0]}
    }
    write-output $MediaID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV files are not huge, it is easier to use [Import-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Import-Csv) instead of splitting the files by hand:

```
$BackupStatus = Import-Csv "Sourcefile1.csv"
$TapesUsed = Import-Csv "Sourcefile2.csv"
```

This will generate a list of objects for each file. You can then compare these lists quite easily:

```
Foreach ($Entry in $BackupStatus) {
    $Match = $TapesUsed | Where {$_.JobID -eq $Entry.JobID}
    if ($Match) {
        $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{"JobID" = $Entry.JobID ; [...] ; "TapeID" = $Match.TapeID # replace [...] with the properties you want to use
        Export-Csv -InputObject $Output -Path <OUTPUTFILE.CSV> -Append -NoTypeInformation        }

}
```

This is a relatively verbose variant, but I prefer it like this.
I am checking for each entry in the first file whether there is a matching entry in the second. If there is one I combine the required fields from the entry of the first list with the ones from the entry in the second list into one object that I can then export very comfortably using [Export-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Export-Csv).

Comment: Thank You! Your help is appreciated! :)